# Angular 2 Feature Modules for Headers and Footers

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Right now, I have a generic set-up where I am loading several standard components into a common page header, several components into a common page footer, and the changeable page content is displayed through a `<router-outlet>`--kind of like so.

**app.component.ts**

```
<div> Several header components loaded and displayed here. </div>
<router-outlet>
<div> Several footer components loaded and displayed here. </div>
```

All of that works fine--except that I really want to further compartmentalize the site. There are a total of about 20 components that are loading in the header and the footer. I really don't want to clutter up my `app.module.ts`, my `app.component.ts`, or the main `app-routing.module.ts` with all of these common components and the routes from their many links. I would much prefer to move them into their own feature modules.

I have already migrated all of the components for the common page header to a folder called `common-header` and all of the components for the common page footer  to a folder called `common-footer`. (At least the app directory is not so cluttered.)

I even created modules called `common-header.module` and `common-footer.module`, respectively. I created a `common-header.component` and `common-footer.component` to wrap the html to call of the respective header and footer components.

How can I call and display the content from these common header and footer feature modules on every page?

Comment: I don't see how splitting components into a shared module and "call and display ... on every page" is related. What is the problem? What have you tried? What is "every page"?

Comment: The site will have many feature modules. I simply want to put all the elements for the common header into one module, the elements for the common footer into another module, and then call and display the contents of the components in those two modules on every logical page. Obviously, Angular2 is an SPA framework with only one real page. I am referring to virtual pages as opposed to actual ones.

Comment: It doesn't matter what module the components are in. Just ensure you have the components in `exports` of the feature module and the feature modules in `imports` of the modules where you want to use the components (and directives and pipes)

Comment: Wow! What an easy fix. Thank you Gunter! If you can post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what module the components are in. Just ensure you have the components in exports of the feature module and the feature modules in imports of the modules where you want to use the components (and directives and pipes)

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [DirectiveA, PipeB, ComponentC],
  declarations: [DirectiveA, PipeB, ComponentC]
})
class MySharedModule{}
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, MySharedModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [Bootstrap],
})
class AppModule{}
```

and add the shared module to `imports` this way in whatever module you want to reuse directives or pipes of this module.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help Gunter! It worked perfectly!